# Resized image in OpenCV doesn't display correctly in Qt4 (PyQt4)

Tags: qt, python-3.x, opencv, qt4, pyqt4

I am trying to load a `.jpg` or `.png` image from the disk using OpenCV and display it in a `QLable` in my GUI. I did all the stuff of resizing and converting from BGR to RGB. Sometimes I get a perfect result :

[image: Correct image]

And sometimes I get rubbish :

[image: Incorrect example]

Here is the code of this example :

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QImage, QPixmap, QLabel, QPushButton, QFileDialog
import cv2

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
window.setLayout(layout)
display = QLabel()
display.setMinimumSize(600, 400)
layout.addWidget(display)
button = QPushButton('Load', window)
layout.addWidget(button)


def read_image():
    path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(window)
    if path:
        picture = cv2.imread(path)
        if picture is not None:
            scaling_factor = min(display.width()/picture.shape[1], display.height()/picture.shape[0])
            width = round(picture.shape[1] * scaling_factor)
            height = round(picture.shape[0] * scaling_factor)
            picture = cv2.resize(picture, (width, height))
            print(path, scaling_factor, picture.shape)
            image = QImage(picture.tobytes(),  # The content of the image
                           picture.shape[1],  # The width (number of columns)
                           picture.shape[0],  # The height (number of rows)
                           QImage.Format_RGB888)  # The image is stored in 3*8-bit format
            display.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image.rgbSwapped()))
        else:
            display.setPixmap(QPixmap())

button.clicked.connect(read_image)
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: I think you'll need to provide two example image files (one that works and one that doesn't) if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: can you print the width of your resized image and the "width step" (number of bytes used per row)?

Comment: @Micka, excuse me, but I have no idea how to find this "width step", I don't know how to extract a row from a QImage

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the size of your image and the size of the resized image. If the size of the picture is not divisible by (width, height), the image will not be displayed correctly. I also had similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026635/resized-opencv-image-is-not-displayed-correctly-on-qwidget-c?noredirect=1#comment116738485_66026635) .OpenCV’s step is a size_t, it needs to be cast to int when you convert the image into QImage.

```
image = QImage(picture.tobytes(),  # The content of the image
                       picture.shape[1],  # The width (number of columns)
                       picture.shape[0],  # The height (number of rows)
                       static_cast<int>(picture.step), # cast width step to int
                       QImage.Format_RGB888)  # The image is stored in 3*8-bit format
```